# What do we use for "not a question" posts?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, vote-to-close

So, since the changes to the close and flag reasons we lost the ability to mark "not a question" as a reason.

We can still use that reason, for posts that are simply guides to fix something but aren't actual questions.

What reason should we use to flag / close those now?  Or, can we resurrect the "not a question" reason?

Comment: We're "supposed" to use "Unclear". Yeh, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Depending the post quality:

- it's most likely a rant in disguise: primally opinion based
- something that you can't make head or tails: unclear
- just bug reports (OT -> bug).

If you see something unanswerable in it's current form and no editing can salvage the situation, it probably need to be closed.

If it can be saved of that fate through editing then is not close worthy but if the quality is (very) bad, you can ask to *La cosa nostra* in the chat room for a fitting close reason.

Comment: What about posts that are just "guides" in and of themselves that don't actually ask a question?

Comment: @ThomasW. I normally go like this when closing a question: "Not about Ubuntu" -> opinion based -> too broad -> unclear -> other OT reasons -> duplicate. If the guide is not about Ubuntu, OT, if the guide is just "this is the best for everybody, I'm right?" opinion based, if the guide is "fixing the 101 problems" too broad; "this is how you setup a server" unclear what you are asking, "fixing the bug #12345678" and company -> OT.